# Handling 2.3 million records and calling REST service

Tags: java, spring-boot

I have a use-case where I need to fetch all records from database and call a REST service based upon data from each of those records.Size of records are around 2.3 million.

After completing process I need to generate Excel file based upon my business logic.I am wondering if there is any best approach to do this.

Answer (score 0):

If this one time service call, it's OK. But i see an issue if this service is being called multiple time.

Speaking about approach, i think you can use spring-batch for simplifying your development.

In context of rest services you can use pagination to fetch records if service permits you. But this will take multiple service calls.

Comment: Sorry for confusion, I need to call REST service based upon data in each record I am fetching from database.Size of records is 2 million.

Answer (score 0):

to show your record in rest you may be you can use `Page<Entity>` to paging your restful , to generate in excel you can jaspersoft to